# Why is my click event is taking last event?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

[image]

When i click on sort-asc or sort-desc font awesome icon always taking last event is firing. what could be the wrong.

Custom css added to stack up and down arrow.

```
     .custom{
         margin-left: -9px;
      }

      <table class="table table-stripped mt-2">
     <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of colNames" >
      {{col["vname"]}}
      <span>
          <i (click)="$event.stopPropagation();sortAsc(col)" class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
          <i (click)="$event.stopPropagation();sortDesc(col)" class="fa fa-sort-desc custom"></i>
      </span> 
    </th>

  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let movie of content">
    <td>{{movie.id}}</td>
    <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
    <td>{{movie.rank}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it a problem in the methods sortAsc and sortDesc or is it with the fontawsome icons? Change <td> to <th>

Comment: If i remove custom class it is working, but i need style

Comment: Can you show code of ```sortAsc``` and ```sortDesc```?

Comment: sortDesc(col){
    console.log(col); }

Comment: Add all the code the original question by editing

Comment: If the question is about the custom class. Please describe what the problem is. What did you want to solve when you added custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Now I get it. You want to stack the icons above each other so that you can press either asc och desc arrow. But then both click-events hits because you added the custom margin: -9px. 
The reason for this is because the `<i>` elements are located above each other.

Solution:

Its always either desc or asc. It cant be anything else so you dont need to show both at the same time. When you get the list the first time its often desc? so show only the asc symbol. When you list id asc show only desc icon.

ex: windows file explorer works like this

Comment: Thank you, If am showing single element then custom css is not required. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome! And it will be easier for the end user to click on it because the click area can be bigger this way